# Is it possible to upload my own PDF to kindle app for windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, kindle

Unlike "kindle for windows", for Windows 8 metro version of kindle app where is no "My Kindle Content" folder where i can place my own PDF files. Is it any way i can upload my own PDF file to it? I'm using Windows 8 Pro, not an RT.

Comment: Since you haven't received any reply on this question, have you tried asking Amazon support, or posting on their forums? It's possible that no one here knows, or maybe no one has used the Kindle MUI app. My advice in the mean time would be to just use the desktop version of Kindle.

Comment: @allquixotic Sure thing, if no one answers question after reward is set i will ask amazon. But amazon is a big company that has thousands of questions each day, so it will be very hard to evade they level-1 "sorry for inconvenience" support and receive real answer :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Amazon, no. Look at http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200939480. The last entry is:

> **Are Personal Documents supported?**
>
> Sending Personal Documents to Kindle for Windows 8 is not currently supported.

So no, sorry to have to tell you that, however the phrasing suggests that eventually, maybe.